# Optimizar código sucio para crear .zip

Tags: php

encuentre este fragmento de código Googleando.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['crear-respaldo'])){
    $file   = './respaldos/respaldo-'.date('d-m-Y-g-i-a').'.zip';
    $r      = zip('./', $file);
    if($r === true) {   echo '<h3 style="font-family:Courier New;"><a href="'.$file.'">Archivo comprimido con &eacute;xito</a></h3>';   }
    else            {   echo '<h3 style="font-family:Courier New;">Oops: algo ha ocurrido</h3>Response: ';  print_r($r);                }
} elseif(isset($_FILES) && count($_FILES)==0){ ?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return (this.archivo.value!='')">
    <a href="?crear-respaldo">Descargar c&oacute;digo</a>
</form>
<?php }
elseif( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['code']['tmp_name'],'./code.zip') ){ unzip();    
} else {    
echo '<h3 style="font-family:Courier New;">Oops: algo ha ocurrido</h3>';    }

function zip($source, $destination){ 
    if(!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)){  return false;   }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if(!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)    ){  return false;   }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if(is_dir($source) === true){
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file){
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )  continue;

            $file = realpath($file);
                if(is_dir( $file)===true){  $zip->addEmptyDir(  str_replace($source.'/', '', $file.'/'));   }
            elseif(is_file($file)===true){  $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source.'/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file)); }
        }
    } elseif(is_file($source) === true){    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source)); }

    return $zip->close()? true:array($source, $destination, $zip);
}
?>
```

Me preguntaba si se puede optizar o reconfigurar para que haga un trabajo más limpio y por supuesto más seguro, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: sucio no esta, el lo que no esta es identado del todo bien.

Comment: Ese fragmento funciona muy bien, pero no sé si es seguro o estable.